# What can I do in my code or layout to improve AdMob RPM?

Tags: android, admob

I have two applications on Google Play using AdMob monetization. One is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=karnagh.ammsoft.karnagh and the other is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=componentspinout.ammsoft.componentspinout.

Both applications have similar number of impressions (around 5000 per day). But Kmap Solver (the first link) performs lower with around $0.1 RPM. Component Pinouts (the second link) have a $0.35 to $0.5 RPM and usually is more lucrative.

I'm posting both my layouts and code as a reference:

KMAP APP LAYOUT:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <karnagh.ammsoft.karnagh.PageViewImage
        android:id="@+id/pageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.26"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

COMPONENT PINOUTS APP:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    tools:context="componentspinout.ammsoft.componentspinout.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/componentsView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The code to start ads is the same located on OnCreate of Activity:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**My question is:** Is there anything in my layout or code to improve APP RPM in Layout. Both Applications have AdView on the bottom of a Layout with SMART_BANNER setting.

Is it true that I need to set Location Permission so AdView object can select a better local AD?

Answer (score 1):

Generaly for admob :

> I'm simply showing one interstitial ad/session = low number of
>   impressions, high RPM. I could also spam my users with ads = high
>   number of impressions, low RPM. In the end you'll get the same result
>   but perhaps less annoyed users with the first method.

I think it's because of that

(From: http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/10955-tips-higher-admob-rpm.html)